# Breaking change to get filename without extension in Swift2

Tags: ios, filenames, swift2

In Swift1, we can get file short name without extension by following code:

```
self.name = pathFilename.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension
```

While I updated to Swift 2, this API is not available anymore. With the warning message, I have to use NSURL. So the new code will be:

```
var filename = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: str).lastPathComponent
filename = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filename!).URLByDeletingPathExtension?.relativePath
```

It is too complex API breaking change. Is there a better way that could make it simpler?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not:

```
self.name = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: str).URLByDeletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent
```

I'm not fluent in Swift so there may be some missing `!` or `?` needed in there.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/myFile.html")
if let fileName = url?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent {
    // fileName: myFile
    self.name = fileName
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This work on **Swift 5.5**:

```
let nameOnly = (fileName as NSString).deletingPathExtension
let fileExt  = (fileName as NSString).pathExtension
```